# Define java option in with sbt-native-packager

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, sbt-native-packager

I have this build.sbt file :

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
import NativePackagerKeys._

packageArchetype.java_application

name := """IdTabDriver"""
version := "1.0.0.1"

name in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageSummary in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageDescription in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

maintainer in Windows := "Access France"

organization := "Access France"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

mappings in Universal ++= directory("keys")

batScriptExtraDefines in Windows += """set _JAVA_OPTS=%_JAVA_OPTS% -Dconfig.file=%IDTABDRIVER_HOME%\\conf\\application.conf"""

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.10",
  "org.rxtx" % "rxtxcomm" % "2.0-7pre1"
)
```

I want to set some parameters (define from now in application.conf) but the `batScriptExtraDefines` seems to be ignored... It is parsed by my IDE as conform symbol but it doesn't affect the generated .bat ...

I have also tried to add

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  //app parameters
  "-Dhttps.port=44360",
  "-Dhttps.keyStore=keys/server.p12",
  "-Dhttps.keyStoreType=pkcs12",
  "-Dhttps.keyStorePassword=12345678"
)
```

But it doesn't make anything.

What have I missunderstood ?

PS: I'm using sbt-native-packager 0.8.0

Comment: Sorry, `javaOptions in Universal` only work for `1.0.3` and above.

Comment: Ok, si how can i do it ? It seems that conf in m'y config file seems to be ignored

Comment: Try removing the extra `packageArchetype.java_application`, this causes problems as play and your build apply it. If the `batScriptExtraDefines` don't work this looks like a bug. You can open an issue. However 0.8.x issue are unlikely to be fixed. Only if it affects the 1.x branch as well.

Comment: I have already tryed to remove the packageArchetype.

So I have no solutions ? Because for now I have to copy a modified version of the generated /bat at each installation...